# How to edit tsql man pages?

Tags: 14.04, manpage

I've done some Googling and searched on [askubuntu](http://askubuntu.com) and haven't found my answer yet. I'd like to make some minor edits to the `tsql` man pages on my system only, to clarify things. I've found the man page path with `man -w tsql`. How do I edit them?

Thank you.

- Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS

Answer (score 1):

You can do this easily using `vim` or `gedit`.

As `vim` and `gedit` can edit the zipped files, you can do :

```
vim "$(man -w tsql)"
gedit "$(man -w tsql)"
```

`$()` is the shell command substitution pattern, which will be replaced by the output of `man -w tsql`. So if the output of `man -w tsql` is `/usr/share/man/man1/tsql`, the above commands are equivalent to :

```
vim /usr/share/man/man1/tsql
gedit /usr/share/man/man1/tsql
```

Comment: Can I do the same thing with nedit? I prefer nedit as an editor.

Comment: @Bulrush Check my edits..  think you have meant `gedit`..if you meant `nedit` then the answer is no, you can't do it with `nedit`..why using `nedit` when there is a far better editor like `gedit` is available..

Comment: I don't really like vim, I like nedit. It meets my needs.

Comment: @Bulrush What about `gedit` ? You can't directly edit compressed files using `nedit` ..you need to uncompress it first, then edit with `nedit` and then compress back again....I think using `gedit` might be your best bet here if you don't like `vim`..

Answer (score 0):

you can use an application named [gmanedit](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/gmanedit).

Install it:

```
sudo apt-get install gmanedit
```

[image]

And now you can open the man page of `tsql`. Normally the man pages are located under `/usr/share/man/` directory.

locate the `tsql` man page then you can edit with the application above